# Having trouble with ternary heap sort logic

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

I just want to note that this is an index 1 based array heap sort, since if the calculations started at 0 it would mess up the logic. The boilerplate logic was hinted at by the textbook, and our professor expects us to follow along. So, I am planning to stick with the general pattern here.

**Issue:**

Heap sort is kind of working, but the 1st popped value is almost always wrong. I've ran the program very many times to see if I saw a pattern in error. Sometimes the program will fully sort. Sometimes a random value or 2 are out of place (excluding the first value outputted which seems to be wrong 95% of the time). Check out the most recent output:

```
[20, 14, 411, 157, 37, 295, 549, 682, 686, 41]
37
14
20
41
295
157
411
549
682
686

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**My attempt at finding a solution:**

This code is pretty terse as some logic is from our textbook, but for binary heap. I basically added methods and am trying to fix the logic from binary heap sort to ternary heap sort. If any explanation of logic is needed, I will gladly explain what the algorithm is doing.

First I thought if the first value is almost always wrong and I am doing index 1 based sorting, perhaps index 0 is somehow not getting accounted for? Sadly doesn't seem to be the case, check the output above. It would be 791 not 135 as output if this was so.

Then I thought perhaps one of my methods that handles values are off by one... I tried fiddling with that and don't seem to get any progress (unless I am missing something).

Finally, looked back at my logic: a parent of an index is (k+1)/3 , a child is 3k, 3k-1, 3k+1. I thought this is correct for index 1 based heap sort.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class HeapSort {
    static Random rand;

    // This class should not be instantiated.
    private HeapSort() { }

    /**
     * Rearranges the array in ascending order, using the natural order.
     */
    public static void sort(Comparable[] pq) {
        int n = pq.length;

        // heapify phase
        for (int parent = (n+1)/3; parent >= 1; parent--)
            sink(pq, parent, n);

        // sortdown phase
        int parent = n;
        while (parent > 1) {
            exch(pq, 1, parent--);
            sink(pq, 1, parent);
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     * Helper functions to restore the heap invariant.
     ***************************************************************************/

    private static void sink(Comparable[] pq, int parent, int n) {
        while (3*parent <= n) {
            int child = 3*parent;
            // check children neighbors left and right, since there are 3 children per parent
            if (child < n && less(pq, child, child+1)) child++;
            else if (child < n && less(pq, child, child-1)) child--;

            if (!less(pq, parent, child)) break;
            exch(pq, parent, child);
            parent = child;
        }
    }

    /***************************************************************************
     * Helper functions for comparisons and swaps.
     * Indices are "minus 1" to support 1-based indexing.
     ***************************************************************************/
    private static boolean less(Comparable[] pq, int i, int j) {
        return pq[i-1].compareTo(pq[j-1]) < 0;
    }

    private static void exch(Object[] pq, int i, int j) {
        Object swap = pq[i-1];
        pq[i-1] = pq[j-1];
        pq[j-1] = swap;
    }

    // print array to standard output
    private static void show(Comparable[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads in a sequence of strings from standard input; heapsorts them;
     * and prints them to standard output in ascending order.
     */
    public static Integer[] createIntegerKeys(int length) {
        rand = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        // populate list
        while(keys.size() < length) {
            int i = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            if (!keys.contains(i)) {
                keys.add(i);
            }
        }
        // shuffle list
        Collections.shuffle(keys);
        System.out.println(keys);

        Integer[] shuffled = keys.toArray(new Integer[keys.size()]);
        return shuffled;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = createIntegerKeys(10);
        HeapSort.sort(a);
        show(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 thank you for your advice, I'll try to fix that. Before I do so, I just want to make sure I understand- are you referring to the exch and less methods? I was under the impression I had to have it like so since having 3 children instead of 2 children makes the math a little more complex.

Comment: Update: Tried revising it by inputting the array as size 11, then ignore index 0 so there are 10 values. After doing this, the output is nonsense just as when I posted this question. I changed exch and less to not be -1, and array length is -1 instead, so it is "10" values.

Comment: In `sink()`, elaborate the comment `check children …` - you seem to intend to find the max key. Only then, check the code to implement what you intend.